# Status of al Waqidi as a narrator?

Tags: hadith, history, ilm-ar-rijal

I know there is a lot of criticism for [Al-Waqidi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Waqidi) by the scholars and muhadditheen (scholars of hadith). They accuse him of being a liar and unreliable. But some scholars say he is trustworthy, such as al Al-Dhahabi and Ibn Kathir.

From a maghazi (Prophetic biography) historical point of view, **do we reject everything Al-Waqidi has to say?**